# How to push these variable into an array and return their whole result as a single array

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want execute three queries independently to get three different rows from the database and want return their result as a single array. I am doing this as in image but its not working:

[image]

I also try to use push method as you can see in the comments and that one also disappoint me. Need your kind help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried php method `array_merge()` ?

```
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: thanks. array_merge return just a single row. but this worked for me .. $array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);..... this line of code helped me too....  $array = [$pool1,$pool2,$pool3];